# ExpressJS: Getting parsed and raw body simultaneously

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get both parsed body of a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post request and the raw body.

I found similar questions around here but non with a working answer.

I tried using `raw-body` but it ignores this kind of conetnet type.

Now I'm trying to use `body-parser` like so: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());` - it correctly populates the `req.body` but the question is how can I get the raw body as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible via bodyParser API to get the raw request body utilizing the `verify` function.

It is invoked before the stream is parsed with the raw body available as its third argument.

Note that it is a buffer, so you need to call `toString` if you want it as such:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  verify: function(req, res, body) {
    req.rawBody = body.toString();
  }
}));
```